# Which Steam badges can be currently obtained without any game cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

What are all of the badges that anyone can get right now, presuming they have the materials, that aren't game dependent?

Like, "Gem Maker", for turning Cards into Gems.

Is there one for making a Booster Pack from Gems, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking [here](https://steamtradingcards.fandom.com/wiki/Badges) and [here](https://steamdb.info/badges/) you can see that the non game dependent are:

- The Community Leader badge
- The, so far, 15 Years of Service badges
- And the Gem badge

Plus some other ones that are impossible to get because they are either only earn-able during a limited time, or are for valve employees, translators or mods.

Comment: How do you get the auction badge right now, when that event ended over four years ago?

Comment: Oh whoops you're right, you can't. I'll fix that right away, sorry!

Comment: Hmm... Can you get Collection Agent (50+ games in your library), though free games alone? They seem to at least count some of my free games...

Comment: I don't think free games count towards those badges because the game count on my profile is lower than the one in my library by about 20 games. I'm quite sure the badge counts the one on your profile, so that means no free games.

Answer (score 4):

I got 100+ Badge - Power Player, After I bought 100 games on steam.